# NestJS: My controller doesn't send the response

Tags: nestjs

I had a controller that didn't send the response back.

```
@Controller('/foo')
export class FooController {
  @Post()
  public async getBar(@Body() body: DTO, @Res() res) {
    const response = await this.doSomething(body);
    return response;
  }
}
```

I had to use the `res.send` method:

```
@Controller('/foo')
export class FooController {
  @Post()
  public async getBar(@Body() body: DTO, @Res() res) {
    const response = await this.doSomething(body);
    res.send(response);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cause was the `@Res() res` parameter. If you delete it, the response will be sent correctly:

```
@Controller('/foo')
export class FooController {
  @Post()
  public async getBar(@Body() body: DTO) {
    const response = await this.doSomething(body);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: Incase you need to modify the response object, see this warning from Nest: 
Nest detects when the handler is using either @Res() or @Next(), indicating you have chosen the library-specific option. If both approaches are used at the same time, the Standard approach is automatically disabled for this single route and will no longer work as expected. To use both approaches at the same time (for example, by injecting the response object to only set cookies/headers but still leave the rest to the framework), you must set the passthrough option to true in the @Res({ passthrough: true }) decorator.

Comment: In my case, I removed the @Res() but all GET method don't return any response body. Do you guys know why it happen?

Answer (score 8):

You have to use `@Res({ passthrough: true })` if you want the response to be send using the Nest way.

If you want to send the response like on Express framework use `@Res()` and add code `res.status(200).send()`

https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers

> WARNING Nest detects when the handler is using either @Res() or
> @Next(), indicating you have chosen the library-specific option. If
> both approaches are used at the same time, the Standard approach is
> automatically disabled for this single route and will no longer work
> as expected. To use both approaches at the same time (for example, by
> injecting the response object to only set cookies/headers but still
> leave the rest to the framework), you must set the passthrough option
> to true in the @Res({ passthrough: true }) decorator.